WPF TabControl Change Tab when doubleclicking in Datagrid
As stated in the title I have data in a datagrid in WPF C# and a tabcontrol with 3 tabs.
I want to be able to switch from tab3 to tab2 after doubleclicking in the datagrid.
I found that this is a kind of specific problem that it doesn't work properly when I just use:
tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 1;

But all other fixes don't seem to work for me. I tried invoking the action. I tried to set the focus on the window, on the tabcontrol and so on and it still wouldn't work.
So I'm finally searching help from you guys.
Could it be that the following error has something to do with it?
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''CheckBox' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Content.Text; DataItem='DataGridCell' (Name=''); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

The error originates in making cells in the datagrid blank when they contain NaN.
Here the XAML Code I use for it. I found it also on stack overflow.
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text,
     Mode=OneWay, 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
     Value="NaN">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="-"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

